# JavaScript: What are the standard fields for an exception object triggered by eval()?

Tags: javascript, exception, eval

Using JavaScript within Firefox 8.0+, I noticed an exception object from a failed eval() results in two fields: `fileName` and `lineNumber`.

Are these specified by the ECMA standard, or are they JavaScript virtual machine dependent?

Thanks.

Comment: Nothing here http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf

Answer (score 1):

According the the ES 5 spec (section 15.11.5), instances of "Error" objects have no special properties. The prototypes have "name" and "message" properties, again according to the spec, but it's a little confusing and I can't tell for sure if those are supposed to be visible or if they're internal things.

Comment: They're visible. Internal properties are explicitly noted as such when mentioned.

Comment: @gsnedders Oh OK right; they use that "[[whatever]]" notation etc.  Thanks!